# how does mootools make periodical() work the same in all browsers?

Tags: javascript, mootools

If you use setInterval with some code, the speed is different in different browsers.
But with if i use the periodical() from mootools the speed is almost exactly the same, how does it do that? can someone show me an example and explain?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like mootools (as of [version 1.3.2](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.2/mootools.js)) just calls through to `setInterval`, so it should behave the same:

```
periodical: function(periodical, bind, args){
    return setInterval(this.pass((args == null ? [] : args), bind), periodical);
}
```

Comment: There was never a workaround for `setTimeout` in the code. (I'm a MooTools dev.)

Comment: but it doesnt, i just tested it and it works the same in chrome and firefox, but if i use a setInterval just like that the differance is huge in speed

Comment: @Petre: Your observed differences must be caused by something else. Please provide a minimal [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) if you can still observe a significant difference.